# A simple algebra that is not semisimple

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, lie-algebras, noncommutative-algebra

I was said that can exists simple algebras $A$ that are not semi-simples in the following sense:

1. $A$ is **simple**, i.e. doesn't have non trivial ideals;
2. $A$ is **not semi-simple**, i.e. is not a semi-simple module over itself.

Does anybody has an example?
Thanks in advance

Comment: [This might help too](http://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?has=7&lacks=8)

Comment: Is not a duplicate since in the other answer there are no examples

Comment: you apparently did not read it then, because the linked question gives Weyl algebras as an example. When I saw your comment about wanting more examples, I added the link above.

Comment: I don't see why you would close the question saying it's a duplicate while it is not since my question is just about explicit and concrete examples while the answer you pointed out it's just a theoretical justification. Anyway your link is very intersting thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, the Weyl algebra $A = \mathbb{C}[x, \partial]/(\partial x - x \partial - 1)$ is a standard example. Proving that it's simple but not semisimple is a nice exercise.