# finite dimensional simple algebras are semisimple

Tags: abstract-algebra

Finite dimensional simple algebras are semisimple.

I've found two different answers and got a bit confused. Any clarification would be of great help!

[A simple algebra that is not semisimple](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2108426/a-simple-algebra-that-is-not-semisimple)

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semisimple_algebra#:~:text=A%20finite%2Ddimensional%20algebra%20is,are%20A%20and%20%7B0%7D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semisimple_algebra#:%7E:text=A%20finite%2Ddimensional%20algebra%20is,are%20A%20and%20%7B0%7D).

Thank you

Comment: What's the question? A simple finite dimensional unital algebra over a field is semisimple (indeed a simple Artinian ring is semisimple). An infinite-dimensional simple algebra need not be semisimple.

Comment: Yes! Is it because of the Wedderburn's theorem? $A$ is simple artinian iff $A \cong M_n(D)$ for some division ring. And this means $A$ is semisimple by Wedderburn's theorem?

Comment: What is causing confusion? Finite dimensional simple -> Artinian simple -> semisimple.    Qiaochu's example is an infinite dimensional simple ring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an unfortunate fact about the terminology that for rings (unlike for, say, modules or Lie algebras) "simple" doesn't imply "semisimple," so let's be clear:

- A *semisimple* ring is a ring which is semisimple as a left module over itself. Other definitions are possible, for example "Artinian and trivial [Jacobson radical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobson_radical)," or "every short exact sequence of left modules splits," and then one has to do some work to show that they're equivalent.
- A *simple* ring is a ring with no nontrivial two-sided ideal.
- Every division ring is simple (exercise). If $R$ is a simple ring, then so is $M_n(R)$ (exercise). So any matrix algebra over a division ring is simple.
- Every division ring is semisimple (exercise). If $R$ is a semisimple ring, then so is $M_n(R)$ (exercise). If $R$ and $S$ are semisimple, then so is $R \times S$ (exercise). So any finite product of matrix algebras over division rings is semisimple.
- The [Artin-Wedderburn theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin%E2%80%93Wedderburn_theorem) asserts the converse: every semisimple ring has the above form.
- Every finite-dimensional algebra over a field $k$ is Artinian, hence is semisimple iff it has trivial Jacobson radical. The Jacobson radical is a two-sided ideal, so any simple ring has trivial Jacobson radical, and so any finite-dimensional simple $k$-algebra is semisimple, and more generally a simple ring is semisimple iff it's Artinian iff (by Artin-Wedderburn) it's a matrix algebra over a division ring.
- The [Weyl algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2108426/a-simple-algebra-that-is-not-semisimple), as stated in the first answer you linked to, is a simple ring which is not Artinian, so it's not semisimple.

For a proof that "semisimple" as defined above is equivalent to "Artinian and has trivial Jacobson radical" see [this blog post](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2012/05/30/the-jacobson-radical/).

Comment: Here's an old math.SE answer where I show that if $R$ is simple then so is $M_n(R)$ and also show that the Weyl algebra is simple: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2540758/an-example-of-a-non-commutative-ring-with-multiplicative-identity-1-in-which-the/2540826#2540826